# UITableView and touching section headers

Tags: iphone, header, uitableview

Can a section header in an instance of UITableView already be made to intercept a touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this by using a `UIControl` custom view for the section header. Then, you can call this method on the `UIControl` to set up your touch:

`- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents`